# iPad can't type in jquery autocomplete input box.

Tags: jquery, ipad, autocomplete

I have a basic autocomplete function that is working on desktop and android, but not iOS.  I am using jQuery Autocomplete, and when using iPad you can't type in the input box.  I am getting no errors when using Edge Inspect.  The page in question is http://www.hastingsdowntown.com/business/business-directory.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Sorry for the static link, there's a lot going on in that page, and since it worked on other browsers I wasn't sure where to even start with code inclusion.  I've found the conflict resides when you pair jQuery UI Autocomplete with Chosen.js.  Chosen uses a CSS class which disables the jQuery UI Autocomplete option in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that since I was using a jquery script called "Chosen", there was a CSS conflict.  It was adding the css property "-webkit-user-select:none;" which disabled input in iPad.